# How can I make a DRY logging configuration in Django that uses the defaults?

Tags: python, django, logging

[Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/) says that you can set `override_default_handlers=False` to have your `LOGGING` config merged with django's `DEFAULT_LOGGING`. I'd like to be able to refernce the handlers in django's `DEFAULT_LOGGING` without having to redefine them in my own logging config. My current `LOGGING` setting looks like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'site_logfile': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        },
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': ('raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers'
                      '.SentryHandler'),
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        }
    }
}
```

I have overrides in my production.py that add the 'sentry' and 'site_logfile' handlers to the default logger, and sets the filename in the 'site_logfile' handler.

However, when I start my development server I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console': Unable to add filter 
'require_debug_true': 'require_debug_true'
```

I'm using Django stable/1.7.x and python 2.7.

Comment: where are you finding `override_default_handlers`? I do not see that referenced anywhere